# Should not we generally use the plural for the tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

As done with other Language sites, should not we generally use the plural for tags, especially when they are about grammar categories?

- [verbs](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbs)
- [nouns](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nouns)
- [pronouns](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronouns)

Comment: I think as long as they're consistent (ie. we don't have both [tag:pronoun] and [tag:pronouns]) either is fine.

Comment: It is not consistent if a tag is using the plural, and another one is using the singular. While it makes sense to have [tag:article] because Esperanto does have just an article (i.e. what in other languages would be the definite article), it doesn't have sense to have [tag:verb] since Esperanto doesn't have a single verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all about shared behaviour. If a behaviour is shared by all verbs, the tag should encompass all the verbs. That is why we use the plural. "Verb" only makes sense if the verb has a specific behaviour that other verbs don't, but in this case a more specific name should be prefered.